# Проблемы с ADOQuery.Insert

Tags: delphi

Имеется `form1` на `кнопка1`, ее обработчик:

```
begin
Form1.ADOQuery1.Insert;
Form2.Show;
end;
```

На `форме2` имеются поля `DBeditN`, связанные с данными в базе. Там же есть кнопка с обработчиком:

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.Post;
Form2.close;
```

Дело в том, что, при попытке добавить новую запись (кнопка1), с BDGrid`a подгружаются данные в DBEdit`ы и происходит редактирование имеющегося поля, новую строку не добавляет! Хотя там же стоит "метод" Insert. Где я натупил?

**Обновление**

Или добавлять в базу нельзя через DBedit'ы?
И придется делать что-то в роде

```
Edit1.Text:=ADOQuery1.FieldByName('ПОЛЕ').AsString ??
```

Comment: отладчиком пройдись... при потере фокуса формы может autopost происходить

Comment: Связаны. ( В том и беда, что работало, работало, я дописывал код, и призошла беда! Может быть, это связано с опциями DBGrid?

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления записей в таблицу пользуйтесь связкой ADOQuery.Append - ADOQuery.Post

```
begin
Form1.ADOQuery1.Append;
Form2.Show;
end;
```

и

```
Form1.ADOQuery1.Post;
Form2.close;
```